# Calling a JavaScript function on an AngularJS Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kibana

I'm working on a custom panel for Kibana. Kibana uses AngularJS. There is a service called "filter". The code for that service can be [seen here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/src/app/services/filterSrv.js). I'm trying to dynamically add a filter at runtime from my panel. From what I can tell, I thought I could do something like this:

```
var n = getName();
var filter = {
  alias: 'My Filter',
  editing: false,
  query: 'name:"' + n + '"',
  type: 'querystring'
};
$scope.dashboard.current.services.filter.set(filter, null, true);
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not seem to work. Instead, I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

After some investigation, I've pinpointed the problem to the fact that set does not appear to be a function on the filter object. I did not see it listed when I ran       `console.log($scope.dashboard.current.services.filter);`

I'm confused. When I look at the code in the service itself, I can clearly see a set method. Yet, its not listed in the console.log. Am I misunderstanding something here? Is there a way to call the `set` function on the filter service? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is very specific to the software you're working with and would therefore be difficult for most here to help you with. I took a quick look at the source there and nothing sticks out to me. Are you seeing the other functions defined in that service listed in console?

Comment: How is `filterSrv` injected? Can you post more code? `set()` is on `filterSrv`, not `dashboard`, so it's more likely that you'd call it like `filterSrv.set(filter, null, true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you might be using services incorrectly, as they are injected objects not usually available on `$scope`. In order to use the filter service, you would do something like the following:

```
// inject the filter service into your controller
myModule.controller('MyCtrl', ['filterSrv', function(filterSrv){
    // create your filter object and add it
    var n = getName();
    var filter = {
        alias: 'My Filter',
        editing: false,
        query: 'name:"' + n + '"',
        type: 'querystring'
    };
    filterSrv.set(filter, null, true);        
}]);
```